# IOS HTML5 cordova app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, html, cordova

We've created an `HTML5 presentation app`. What this app does is simply showing "slides" after each other. These `slides` are built with `images` and `hotspots` on it.

With these `hotspots` you can navigate through other slides. 
Or you can open `popups` and other stuff like a short video.

The problem now is that the app rans `out of memory` every time we open a video, or when we put more then 50 slides in it.

We've compressed all the `images and videos`. All the images are around `30 - 250kb`.

We are using `cordova` to read out our www folder which contains all the HTML,JS,CSS,video and images.

If you need more information,
please ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware that the disk size of an image has nothing to do with the memory an image is using when load. (width x height x 4) is the average memory usage of an image.

Comment: Have you any idea how we can optimalize is then ?

Comment: You can't. Just make sure you unload unused image and do not keep them in memory. But since you are using HTML I don't really see how this is posisble.

Comment: mm strange. How can it be that magazines apps that you can find in the kiosk are not crashing? Our research turned out that the most of them are also HTML5 apps.

Comment: I've developed some like that and never used HTMl 5. Just CoreText or PDF. But some might and they might use some javascript to unload memory, since I'm not a HTML developer I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article from the linkedIn dev team](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5) for tips on managing memory in a HTML5 app with a lot of items (summary: unload images and hide content that is not in view).

Also, try [chrome dev tools profiler](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/profiles) or [safari web inspector profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH4-SW6) to get an idea where your big memory hotspots are, and then measure the impact of any changes you make.